# How can I get these Bootstrap column divs to be uniform length inside of a well?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, styling

I'm working on a thing with Bootstrap/Angular and am using `ng-repeat` to populate divs from an array retrieved from the database. My issue is that while the divs themselves need to have `word-wrap` set to auto, this causes them to be inconsistent heights depending on the content.

I'm displaying three per well, so how would I get all three divs heights to be uniform, depending on the tallest one?

Here's the html:

```
<div class="well tickets" ng-repeat="tickets in chunkedTickets">
   <div class="col-sm-4 task clearfix" ng-repeat="ticket in tickets">`

        <form name="editForm" class="editForm">
           <h4 ng-show="!ticket.edit">{{ticket.name}}</h4>
           <h4 ng-show="ticket.edit">Ticket Name:</h4>
          <!-- more stuff -->

  </div>
</div>
```

chunkedTickets is the array of data chunked into a nested array of threes.
And here is the CSS applying to the well and the 'task' divs:

```
.tickets {
  overflow: auto;
 }

.task {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px #aaaaaa;
  border-left: -5px;
  border-right: -5px;
};
```

The `well` and `clearfix` classes are bootstrap of course. I've tried flexboxes, tried setting a height to 90%, tried everything. I've always been very bad at this, and can't find any help on search since questions are relating to bootstrap's .row class and I need to specifically use .well. I would greatly appreciate some help.

Screenshot of the app now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6ZEX.png

Comment: I would love to help you but it would be much easier to do so with live code. Can you provide a URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm usually using this solution:

http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height

It's pretty robust, just add classes for the row and desired columns (I usually use `row-md-height` and `col-md-height`, for smartphones it's usually not needed.